# Is it possible to check to the position of an iterator in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, foreach, iterator, ruby-1.9.2

Is there a way to get the position of an iterator (how many times it has iterated)?

```
values = (1..100)
values.each do |value|
  if ... % 10 == 1 then puts iterator.count end
end
```

Or do you have to count explicitly:

```
values = (1..100)
counter = 0
values.each do |value|
  if counter % 10 == 1 then puts counter end
  counter += 1
end
```

Is there a cleaner approach?

Ruby 1.9.2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index)

```
values.each_with_index do |value, idx|
  puts idx if idx % 10 == 1
  # do something else
end
```

Or you can use a cooler alternative

```
values.each.with_index do |value, idx|
  # work
end
```

I called it cooler because `#with_index` is relatively less known and it can be combined with `map` (and other methods) to yield interesting results.

Comment: `.with_index` also works for a hash: `hash.each_key.with_index |key, idx|`

Comment: @BSeven: Moreover, it works with any method that returns enumerator :)

Comment: two (minor) notes: 1) `each_with_index` can also be used with `map` (Ruby >= 1.8.7). 2) `values.each.with_index` behaves in fact as `values.map.with_index`.

Comment: @tokland: thanks! Somehow I never tried using `map` with `each_with_index` :)